# Python - How to redirect the errors to /dev/null

Tags: python, linux

I have this fun in my python script

```
def start_pushdata_server(Logger):
    Logger.write_event("Starting pushdata Server..", "INFO")
    retcode, stdout, stderr = run_shell(create_shell_command("pushdata-server 
start"))
```

We want to redirect the standard error from pushdata-server binary to /dev/null

We edit it like this:

```
def start_pushdata_server(Logger):
    Logger.write_event("Starting pushdata Server..", "INFO")
    retcode, stdout, stderr = run_shell(create_shell_command("pushdata-server 
start 2>/dev/null"))
```

but adding the `2>/dev/null` in the Python code isn't valid.

How can we - in Python code - send all errors from "pushdata-server start" to null ?

Comment: You can use `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL`

Comment: [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/405193/python-how-to-redirect-the-errors-to-dev-null)

Comment: Just add the line "stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL" after  the line - Logger.write_event("Starting pushdata Server..", "INFO")  ?